# Extract a matrix from another matrix with specific columns indices c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a matrix `A` and I need to do operations on that matrix and compute a vector of indices `C`. Then, I extract a matrix from `A` containing the columns indexed by `C` and I do the same operations on the resulting matrix. I repeat this process `M` times, where `M` is a big number. Here is a pseudo code of the process:

```
vector<vector<int>> A;

for(int k=1;k<=M;++k)
{
    funtion(A); //do some operations on A and compute a vector C of indices of columns
    extract from A a matrix containing the columns indexed by C and copy this matrix in A
}
```

My question is: what is the best way to extract the matrix indexed by `C` in terms of processing times? and is it preferable to use lists rather then vectors?

Comment: If you only care about columns, then transpose the matrix. Then you can work on rows, and that would make things much simpler (and potentially more efficient).

Comment: `int k=1,k<=M` looks like a potential problem (and is also syntactically incorrect) but without more code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Define "processing times". Do you have a measurable performance bottleneck with this approach?

Comment: Generally a flat `vector` is faster than a 2D one. You can always emulate 2D with access offsets. You may also want to use a matrix numerical library if you're concerned about performance. Many of these use SIMD extensions to do the math significantly faster.

Comment: @tadman I mean by processing time the execution time of the algorithm.  Can you tell me about the matrix numerical library that I can use ?

Comment: There's a *lot* of high-performance libraries out there. Find one that its your particular needs and it'll help you out significantly with vector and matrix math.

Comment: There's no algorithm here that I can comment on.

Comment: @cigien  do you mean that using the transpose will help in push-back the columns indexed by C?